# Writing values to an empty dataframe column in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

There is a dataframe with some values. I need to add an empty column to it, so that I can then fill in its individual cells with values when information on them becomes available. The type of values is known in advance, for example, let it be Float64, but if during initialization I set the contents of the column as "missing", then the type of the column is also displayed as "Missing" and no numeric values can be written there later. Here is an example illustrating the problem:

```
df = DataFrame(a = 1:3, b = 1.0:3.0)
insertcols!(df, 3, :c => missing)
df.b[1] = 5.0 # it works
df.c[1] = 7.0 # give an error
```

What is the right thing to do in this situation? Is needed to change the way of empty column initialization or the way of recording in its cells?

Comment: Why do you need it to be empty or have missing in it? just initialise as zero? Or make a `Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}` if you want it to hold both missings and floats

Comment: Initializing with zeros is not a good idea, because zero can also be the answer that we need to write down and which is valuable as the information. If the column has already been filled with zeros, then we will not be able to distinguish the cell with the answer from the cell with the initial value. If the cells are initialized with the "missing" value, then at any time we can request a values of all non-empty cells and see all the currently available values, including zeros. Initializing with a mixture of missings and floats can really solve the problem

Comment: As a side note `df[:c]` is not a valid syntax in DataFrames.jl. A recommended way to write it is `df.c`. A more advanced syntax is either `df[:, :c]` or `df[!, :c]` (what Przemysław has shown), but it is rarely needed. My recommendation is to stick to `df.c` most of the time - it is also easiest to type.

Comment: Thanks! Next, I will follow the recommended syntax

Comment: I've updated my example to match the modern syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way you could try:

```
insertcols!(df,  :c => Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing,nrow(df)))
```

or:

```
df[!,:c] = Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing,nrow(df))
```

or shorter as mentioned by @Milan Bouchet-Valat:

```
df[!,:c] = missings(Float64, nrow(df))
```

Comment: `missings(Float64, nrow(df)` is a shorthand for `Vector{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing,nrow(df))`.